# Bad response from Ajax call when using IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Why does this script work beautifully in firefox and chrome but not in IE?  I'm using IE8 and it returns -1 all the time.  It seems to not be cached either. Also the ajaxurl is not cross domain, the page is in the same domain.

```
jQuery('#btnqqf').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();            


     jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false, timeout: (300*1000)}); 
     var data = {action: 'qqf_action',   txtName: jQuery('#txtName').val()};

     var d = new Date();
     jQuery.post(ajaxurl + '?nocache=' + d.getTime(), data, function(response) {
     alert(response);              

 });
});
```

Comment: I believe txtName should be jQuery('#txtName').val();

Comment: have you tried adding `dataType: 'json'` in your ajaxSetup (if it is json)

Comment: no luck with setting the dataType.  I tried json, text, xml, html, etc..  the script returns just a string.

Comment: Appears to be a wordpress issue. The ajaxurl page is returning -1 if not logged in. Im using the hooks: 
add_action('wp_ajax_qqf_action', 'qqf_action_callback'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_qqf_action', 'qqf_action_callback');
but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_qqf_action', 'qqf_action_callback');`
```

was supposed to be:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_qqf_action', 'qqf_action_callback');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably IE does not set the required MIME type or some other header.. try debugging it by handling all events:

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl + '?nocache=' + d.getTime(), data)
    .success(function(response) {
        alert("success! " + response);
    })
    .error(function() {
        alert("error");
    })
    .complete(function() {
        alert("complete");
    });
```